# boost::lexical_cast<signed char> cannot handle negative numbers?

Tags: c++, boost, char, signed, lexical-cast

This short C++ program behaves in a way which baffles me:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main(void) {
    signed char c = -2;
    assert(c == -2);
    c = boost::lexical_cast<signed char>(std::string("-2"));
    std::cout << c << "\n";
}
```

Using `g++ 5.2.1` and `boost-1.58.0`, I get:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
>     what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target

Why can't Boost cast from string "-2" to `signed char` given that the value `-2` is representable by this type?

Comment: Because `lexical_cast` behaves as if the conversion is done via a stringstream, and `operator>>` for `signed char` reads characters, not numbers.

Comment: How can I obtain desired behaviour?

Comment: Never mind, I can do `boost::lexical_cast<int>(str)` and then convert to `signed char` checking the range...

Comment: I suggest adding this as the answer

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use Boost:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
int tmp = boost::lexical_cast<int>(std::string("-2"));
char c = boost::numeric_cast<signed char>(tmp);
```